# Is !runaway command useful when the reported threads are from the thread pool?

Tags: .net, multithreading, threadpool, windbg

To the best of my understanding a thread pool thread serves different "masters" during its lifetime and in a busy application such a thread may actually live for long.

It seems that such a thread generates a false positive in the `!runaway` output.

In which case the usefulness of this command is greatly reduced.

Am I correct or am I missing something here?

**EDIT1**

And what about the WCF/Asp.NET request threads? Are they recycled as well? If so, then there is nothing left. I/O completion threads are recycled too, of course.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to analyze CPU problems with the **memory** dump? If you could arrange your reply as answer and add some tips, for example - how can I tell if the thread X is a thread pool thread? Is it something at the basis of its stack trace?

Comment: @mark Determining whether a thread is managed by a threadpool involves looking at the lower frames of the callstack. What to look for depends on the threadpool implementation and there are more of those than you can shake stick at. Still it should be apparent by looking at the function names.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. My question is kind of bad, because there are no good answers for it. Could you provide a few tips on high CPU analysis so I could credit you? I am aware of basic technique - check stacks of the runaway threads. But you could have more valuable hints.

Comment: The Windows Performance Toolkit (xperf) is a better tool for CPU analysis. See: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems like a plethora of relevant information on that Defrag-Tools show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To the best of my understanding a thread pool thread serves different "masters" during its lifetime

Yes.

> and in a busy application such a thread may actually live for long.

Yes.

> It seems that such a thread generates a false positive in the !runaway output.

It depends on the definition of "false positive".

In any case it's a matter of interpretation of what you know the application is doing and what you observe it actually does. If that matches, everything is fine, if not: investigate. E.g. if you have a thread pool, expect `!runaway` to become a number expressing the amount of work done.

It's not wrong though: that thread has actually consumed that much CPU time. Thinking this way, it's not a false positive.

The question here is: why do you run `!runaway` in the first place? Probably you want to analyze a performance issue. In such a scenario, crash dumps are not well suited, since they only represent a single point in time. For a performance analysis, you need continuous information.

If you're lucky and you have a lot of experience, you may solve performance issues from crash dumps, e.g. if I recall correctly, famous Mark Russinovich has solved some Exchange Server issue by taking a series (!) of crash dumps, comparing the stack traces and finding out that some virus scanner was doing too much work.

The key point here is: a series of crash dumps so you can confirm it remains e.g. in an endless loop or so. A tool to do this is [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) which has the `-c` switch to trigger at a high CPU. Use it together with `-n` to write a number of dumps and `-s` to define the time between the dumps.

Still, ProcDump is not the ideal tool. What you really need is a tool that breaks down the performance to a single method. Something like [dotTrace Performance Profiler](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) (now part of Resharper Ultimate) or [XPerf](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2008/04/03/windows-performance-toolkit-xperf/) or similar tools.

To answer your question:

> Is !runaway command useful when the reported threads are from the thread pool?

`!runaway` is *correct*. It is helpful for performance analysis in "named" thread (`var t = new Thread();`) situations. It is not very helpful for performance analysis of thread pool threads.